# Text not showing using Native Font on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the new Codenameone plugin (unverified) and decided to try out the new native font.

I initially used Roboto ttf font which I completely changed to `native:MainLight` and removed.

It works fine on Android and Simulator but all text disappeared on iPhone and iPad running iOS 9.2 and 9.1 respectively.

I called:

```
if (Font.isNativeFontSchemeSupported()){
        Dialog.show("Supported?", "Yes it is supported" + Font.getDefaultFont(), "Ok", null);
}
```

which returned true and the Dialog pops up.

Am I missing out something or do I have to add any BuildHint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a temporary issue related to these new font types.

We fixed it and it should already work for new builds going out right now.

Thanks!